# jQuery.trigger("change") not work in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, html-select

I'm writing an automatic testing tool. I use PhantomJS to make some action on a website. Currently, I have a problem like this: When I want to select an option from a select element, I use this sentence:

```
$(query).val(value);
$(query).trigger("change");
```

But it does not work. The website does not respond correctly. However, if I open the website by a browser and type that sentence in console, it work.
So I don't know what happen here. Have anybody meet this situation before? Can you recommend me some method to solve this.

Comment: Try `$(query).change()`

Comment: Is your code executed inside evaluate() function?